# Why the operands of an operator needs to be of the same type?

Tags: c++, types, casting

If I have something like this:

```
int i = 123;
float f = 123.1;

if (f > i) {} else {}
```

The `i` will be promoted to a `float` and the comparison will become `if (float > float)`. My question is why does the `int` variable needs to be promoted to a `float` in the first place, Is it because its easier for the computer to compare two plain numbers than trying to figure out what the bits of each number represent and then compare that?

Comment: Because the C++ rules dictate that to be so.

Comment: It's also true only for the built-in operators, and only in formal sense. E.g. I would be surprised if all compilers will always promote `char` to `int`, as the standard describes, instead of optimizing by the as-if rule.

Comment: `>` only ever makes sense with two operands of the same type. You can only do `(_:int) > (_:float)` when 1) `int` is a subtype of `float` (which is not the case in C++ for technical reasons), or 2) `int` is silently promoted to a `float` (which is not the case in C++ because it would be a bad idea).

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: Well, no, it's because at some point you need to pass these values to the CPU for comparison, and you're going to struggle to get the CPU to compare a floating-point value to an integer. They're entirely different constructs. That higher-level languages like C++ largely abstract that away from you (by allowing you to write `f > i` in the first place) is besides the point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because "There are no numbers". Computers don't compare numbers, and don't work with numbers. They work with, and compare, **bit patterns**.

The fact bit patterns represent numbers is due to the "encoding" we use to represent numbers as bit patterns. And once we choose **an** encoding, operations on numbers become operations on bit patterns. And once we choose **another** encoding, same operations on numbers become **other** operations on bit patterns.

Now, if you have 10 possible way to represent numbers, you should support 100 possible ways to do binary operations (or even 1000, if you also want to consider the result!).

Since this cannot scale, you have to reduce. And the simpler way to reduce is to eliminate similar things by splitting them into parts: first convert all all numbers to go into a common encoding, then operate on that encoding and eventually convert the result back to the desired one.

This is essentially due to the fact that operation on numbers having a same encoding can be implemented easily since **same rules apply everywhere**, and this can be done by **reusing the same circuitry**.

But for this to work, the "common format" must be chosen so that both the operands can be represented. And representing an int into a float has more chances to succeed than representing a float into an int.

Comment: Typically, though, there are 5 methods in use: `signed`, `unsigned`, `bool`, `float` and `double`. The integral types do not differ in bit pattern, just length.

Comment: That "legal" passage is pointless ("Why does C++ do X?" "Because C++ does X" .... pointless). There is a reason that this is how the standard made it. Fortunately you saved the answer by writing that reason in the rest of it.

Comment: @Msalters: same pattern but different length == different pattern if we agree to include the length in the pattern itself. Unless we want to approach a more deep discussion about what hardware does what operation: in that case float and double arithmetic can be seen as integer plush mask and shift, and signed / unsigned and length all converge to a same register-wide "full-adder" plus carry. It's all a matter on how deep or abstract we want to be respect to the OP level. I wanted to be "a little" but not too much.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: That was exactly what I wanted to demonstrate. Many times I read answer that say "the standard requires...". But there must be a reason behind it.  Read again with a little more irony.

Comment: @EmilioGaravaglia: We are not here to write "irony". As I said, that paragraph is 100% meaningless. Best to skip to the actual answer.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: What's the problem? Don't write it!

Comment: I think it's half-way between your points: yes, the standard decided it to be the way it is and @EmilioGaravaglia's explanation may be one of the reasons behind it. BTW, saying just "the standard decided so" sounds like a "o'rly?".

Comment: I'm I awake or there is a comment just below the question saying "*Because the C++ rules dictate that to be so*" that took 2 upvotes?  What I was meant is to say "yes, it is, but there are technical reasons behind it". By removing that part, we only describe the reason. Reasons that -whatever plausible- are not required just by themselves to stay in the standard. The two parts are required.  I understand that for many of you one or both of them are obvious, but they are both formally required.

Answer (score 0):

The rules were written as they were because it was easier for compilers to define a small number of ways of performing operations, along with a means of normalizing operands, than to define a larger number of ways.  Even just considering the six types int, unsigned int, long, unsigned long, float, double, evaluating an expression like `x < y` without converting operands would require special-case code to handle the following cases:

- int/unsigned int (in either order)
- long/unsigned long
- int/float
- long/float
- long/double

In the 1970s, having to handle sixteen different combinations of operand types for `x > y` instead of six would have been excessively expensive, especially given that the compiler would have to generate more complicated code to perform such comparisons "accurately" than would be required if everything were coerced to the same type.

Personally, I think that modern language designers should free themselves from the 1970s mindset, but it seems to have become pretty well established (though it may also be worth noting that if the nasty variable-argument-passing behavior of "long double" hadn't made the type useless, that type would on many platforms have been able to represent the value of every `long` or `unsigned long` value, so promoting fixed float/integer arguments to that type would have yielded semantically-correct results very easily).